# Collision Detection - How to?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently working on a flash game and am rather new to AS 3 or flash. Need some advice in how to implement one of the core elements of my game.

The idea is 2 player competitive snake style game, only the players do not try to kill each other, but try to reach their opponents spawnpoint.

1 of the key parts of the game would be a grid which is created over the stage where either player may use to "Create walls" by passing through points on the grid. I have no idea how to implement this. Currently I have the basics down where there are 2 players with a starting spot, and if either one reaches the other's starting zone, they score a point.

I need some advice in how to go about implementing this feature:

Each point in the grid will start off in a certain state, and when a player passes through that point, it will be "activated". Then the player may move through any adjacent points to the "activated" point, which will generate a wall between both active points, and thats how they will create mazes to protect their starting area.

Should I generate each point individually or create a grid with a simple function:

```
    //function to create grids on the map
    public function createGrid()
    {
        var rows:int = 6;
        var cols:int = 11;
        for (var py:int = 0; py < rows; py++) {
            for (var px:int = 0; px < cols; px++) {
                this.grid = new griDot(player1,player2, this);
                grid.x = 50 + grid.width + 100 * px +10;
                grid.y = 50 + grid.height +100 * py + 10;
                this.addChild(grid);
                }
        }
    }
```

and they are detected with this function(don't laugh i'm pretty noob):

```
    public function checkDotCollision(player)
    {

        if(player1.hitTestObject(grid) == true)
        {
            trace("player dot collision detected");
        }
        if(player2.hitTestObject(grid) == true)
        {
            trace("player dot collision detected");
        }
    }
```

currently only the left most bottom square of the grid is detecting the player. Any help / advice on how to implement this feature would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide you with code, just with an idea.

In your Player class (if you don't have one, you can get away with the dynamic properties of a movieclip but it's not very clean), add a `lastTouchedGriDot` of type `griDot`.

In `checkDotCollision`, check for each tile. You can't do this at the moment; looks like you'll have to maintain a collection for `griDot`s somewhere. So alter `createGrid()` to store the created objects in a collection of sorts.  Then we can check for each tile. So do so. If you've found a hit, do the following:

- If there is no last touched grid point, set the last touched grid point to the one you're touching now.
- If the grid point that was last touched is the same as the one you're touching now, do nothing.
- If the grid point that was last touched is different than the one you're touching now, check if it's adjacent. If so, build a wall. If not, set the last touched grid point to the one you're touching now.

This should provide you with a solid start. You'll have to add wall collisions and checking if there already IS a wall yourself.